# Compute $\lim_{\sigma_2\to0_+}\frac{b_1/\sigma_1 + b_2/\sigma_2}{1/\sigma_1 + 1/\sigma_2}$.

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to find the limit as $\sigma_2 \to 0_+$ for $\cfrac{b_1/\sigma_1 + b_2/\sigma_2}{1/\sigma_1 + 1/\sigma_2}$.

By considering $a/\sigma_2$ we notice that as $\sigma_2 \to 0_+$ our expression goes to infinity. Therefore we only need to consider what happens in $\frac{b_2/\sigma_2}{1/\sigma_2}$ a $\sigma_2 \to 0_+$ which is $b_2$ by La'Hopital's rule.

---

The part that feels too hand wavy is dismissing the $\sigma_1$. I know that's what happens but I don't know how to explain it more rigorously than what I showed above.

Comment: No need for L'Hopital's rule:$$\frac{\frac{b_1}{\sigma_1}+\frac{b_2}{\sigma_2}}{\frac1{\sigma_1}+\frac1{\sigma_2}}=\frac{\frac{b_1\sigma_2}{\sigma_1}+b_2}{\frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1}+1}\to b_2$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no problem using L'Hospital:

$$\lim_{\sigma_2\to0}\frac{\dfrac{b_1}{\sigma_1}+\dfrac{b_2}{\sigma_2}}{\dfrac1{\sigma_1}+\dfrac1{\sigma_2}}=\lim_{\sigma_2\to0}\frac{-\dfrac{b_2}{\sigma_2^2}}{-\dfrac1{\sigma_2^2}}=b_2.$$

---

Without L'Hospital,

$$\lim_{\sigma_2\to0}\frac{\dfrac{b_1}{\sigma_1}+\dfrac{b_2}{\sigma_2}}{\dfrac1{\sigma_1}+\dfrac1{\sigma_2}}
=\lim_{\sigma_2\to0}\frac{\dfrac{\sigma_2b_1}{\sigma_1}+b_2}{\dfrac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1}+1}
=\frac{\lim_{\sigma_2\to0}\left(\dfrac{\sigma_2b_1}{\sigma_1}+b_2\right)}{\lim_{\sigma_2\to0}\left(\dfrac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1}+1\right)}=b_2.$$

Comment: Could you clarify how you got from the LHS to the RHS in the L'Hospital example?

Comment: @financial_physician: by applying the formula, what else ?

Comment: What'd you multiply by to go from $\lim_{\sigma_2\to0}\frac{\dfrac{b_1}{\sigma_1}+\dfrac{b_2}{\sigma_2}}{\dfrac1{\sigma_1}+\dfrac1{\sigma_2}}$ to $\lim_{\sigma_2\to0}\frac{-\dfrac{b_2}{\sigma_2^2}}{-\dfrac1{\sigma_2^2}}$

Comment: @financial_physician: I didn't multiply, I applied L'Hospital. Do you know what it says ?

Comment: Apparently not haha. What I've seen on it is that you need to have $\pm\infty/\pm\infty$ or $0/0$ and then you can take derivatives, but the first equation doesn't look like that. I see now that you do applied La'Hopital's to get the the equality but it doesn't look like the conditions above. Instead of $0/0$ it looks like undef/undef

Comment: @financial_physician: how does $\pm\infty/\pm\infty$ becomes $\text{undef}/\text{undef}$ for the sake of not accepting L'Hospital ?

Comment: I went back and read the [wiki] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) for the formal definition. I guess what I remembered is more how you teach the application of La'Hopital's, not the rule. Thank you!

Comment: @financial_physician: in what country do they spell "La'Hopital" ?

Comment: Haha I’m just spelling it wrong. It’s just that’s how it’s pronounced in English. Thanks for pointing it out. I didn’t notice

Answer (score 3):

Since $\frac{1}{\sigma_{1}}$ is a constant and small compared to $\frac{1}{\sigma_{2}}$ as $\sigma_{2}\rightarrow 0^{+}$, we can remove it from the term. Thus we obtain

$$\lim_{\sigma_{2}\rightarrow 0^+}\cfrac{b_1/\sigma_1 + b_2/\sigma_2}{1/\sigma_1 + 1/\sigma_2}$$
$$=\lim_{\sigma_{2}\rightarrow 0^+}\cfrac{b_1/\sigma_1 + b_2/\sigma_2}{ 1/\sigma_2}$$
$$=\lim_{\sigma_{2}\rightarrow 0^+}\cfrac{b_1/\sigma_1}{ 1/\sigma_2} + \frac{b_2/\sigma_2}{ 1/\sigma_2}$$
$$=\lim_{\sigma_{2}\rightarrow 0^+}\cfrac{b_1\sigma_2}{ \sigma_1} + b_2=b_{2}.$$

In fact we also have $$\lim_{\sigma_{2}\rightarrow 0^-}\cfrac{b_1/\sigma_1 + b_2/\sigma_2}{1/\sigma_1 + 1/\sigma_2}=b_2.$$

Comment: I like the idea of only removing the left hand side of the denominator. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In this answer I think about $\sigma_2 \to 0_+$ as a sequence of numbers tending towards $0$ from the positive side, and assume that we're comfortable with the fact that the limit of the sum is the sum of the limits.

\begin{align*}
\lim_{\sigma_2 \to 0_+} \frac{b_1 / \sigma_1 + b_2 / \sigma_2}{1/\sigma_1 + 1/\sigma_2} &= \lim_{\sigma_2 \to 0_+} \Big( \frac{b_1}{\sigma_1} + \frac{b_2}{\sigma_2} \Big) \frac{\sigma_1 \sigma_2}{\sigma_1 + \sigma_2}\\
&= \lim_{\sigma_2 \to 0_+} \frac{b_1 \sigma_2}{\sigma_1 + \sigma_2} + \lim_{\sigma_2 \to 0_+} \frac{b_2 \sigma_1}{\sigma_1 + \sigma_2}\\
&= \lim_{\sigma_2 \to 0_+} \frac{b_2 \sigma_1}{\sigma_1 + \sigma_2} \text{ (first term certainly goes to zero)}\\
&= b_2.
\end{align*}